# handle events of control dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have created 5 Ajax Tab panels dynamically with following code:

```
   Dim gv As GridView
            ds = gc.GetDataToListBinder("select distinct(tabname) from Parameteronline where isactive='Y'")
            For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

                Dim tpParameter As AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel = New AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel()

                tpParameter.ID = "Panel_" & ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0).ToString()
                tpParameter.HeaderText = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0).ToString()
                TabContainer1.Tabs.Add(tpParameter)
            Next
```

By this i am getting 5 pasnels sucessfully in one container whose Ids are:

Panel_API , Panel_Court , Panel_Jail , Panel_Utilities, Panel_Common

Since all these Ids and panels are been created dynamically, i am not understanding how should i identify the click event on any of the panel?

How to write events for dynamically created tab control?

Although i am using VB.NET answer in C# can also help me.

Please help me.

Comment: Can't you attach the event dynamically as well? Then the sender becomes that tab and you can inspect the name to identify which tab was clicked.

Comment: @ermagana thanx i done it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by following way:

```
Protected Sub TabContainer1_ActiveTabChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
    Handles TabContainer1.ActiveTabChanged
                Dim actTab As String = TabContainer1.ActiveTab.ID.ToString()
                Dim gv As GridView

                ds = gc.GetDataToListBinder("select * from ParameterOnline where TabName='Courts'")

                If actTab = "Panel_Courts" Then
                    gv.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
                    TabContainer1.ActiveTab.Controls.Add(gv)
                End If


            End Sub
```